# drawImage method of canvas is not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The drawimage method is not working. Is there any error in this code?
html:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="350"></canvas>
</div> 
</body>
```

javascript:

```
function init()
{
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');
var chop   = new Image();
chop.src   = "chopper.png";

ctx.drawImage(chop,10,10,200,200);
};

window.onload = function() {init()};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a big error in the code.

The JS won't wait for the image to finish downloading before it tries to draw it.
The window.onload won't guarantee that all async calls are done, either.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () { ctx.drawImage(img, ...); };
img.src = "...";
```

That will now work, regardless of whether the window has done loading or not... (it will have, unless the image is cached).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the image is loaded to draw it:

```
var chop = new Image();

chop.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(chop,10,10,200,200);
};

chop.src = "chopper.png";
```